# Java Android FirebaseMessagingService: onMessageReceived not called at all

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have a problem with my FirebaseMessagingService java class. When I send a notification from the Firebase console the `onMessageReceived` function isn't called at all. But I know I successfully sent the notification, here is my code:

```
package com.nufdev.firelink.other;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.nufdev.firelink.MainActivity;
import com.nufdev.firelink.R;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_send)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected Intent zzaa(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "ZZZA?");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Whenever I send a notification from the Firebase console I only get in the console: `ZZAA`? because of this  :

```
@Override
        protected Intent zzaa(Intent intent) {
            Log.v(TAG, "ZZZA?");
            return null;
        }
```

I have no idea what `zzaa` means and can't find it on Google.
So if you could help me that would be awesome. :D

Comment: did you add correct permission in androidmanifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes I added the internet persmission and add my class as a service too... So i really don't know why the function isn't called...

Comment: What's the point of overriding zzaa method. I am not sure but returning null that should break the code which displays message if there is null check

Comment: I just checked source code and there is null check. Do not override it. As code is hidden returning value used to open an intent when notification clicked if I understood correctly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add this to the manifest (taken from the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client))

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems FCM has two type of notification messages. FCM console always sends "notification message", which triggers onMessageReceived only if app is foreground. 
More details about the concept: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Explanation in FCM quick start sample code:

```
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
```